# Files larger than approx. 500KB resulting in Not found 404 error

Tags: post

I have a code that uses Dropbox, Google Drive and Box APIs to upload files to these services.  For some reasons, the code has started to throw 404 errors whenever a file more than about 500KB is posted using any of the APIs above.  I understand that IIS has settings for incoming post data but this is outgoing post calls using RESTful apis.  I noticed that 404 comes right away when the call is made while smaller files take some time before Ok code is received.  That seems to tell me that the issue is at client side.  Some setting of Net components on the machine is failing for bigger files.  Scratching my head to see where to start looking.  To my recollection, there were no issues with these uploads before. Any inputs?

.Net 4.0 Framework.

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved.

Web.config setting max size was set to too low. Setting `maxAllowedContentLength` fixed it.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
           <!-- 1GB (the value is in Bytes) -->
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```